How to use parameter term names in avg_predictions() or hypotheses() functions?
I am attempting to estimate the difference in predicted probabilities between groups using the avg_predictions() function and the hypothesis argument from the powerful marginaleffects package. However, I am having trouble with term names when multiple variables are included in the by argument. I'd like to use term names rather than the b1, b2, etc., to identify each parameter's position because the positions are not consistent when I run avg_predictions() for different outcomes with same covariate list. Below, I show the code as an example of what I am trying to do.
When I run this:
data("HealthInsurance", package = "AER")
mod <- glm(insurance ~ ethnicity*health + age + married + family + selfemp + region, 
       family = binomial(link = "logit"),
       data = HealthInsurance)

avg_predictions(mod, by = c("ethnicity", "health"), type = "response")

I get the following:
ethnicity health Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %
 cauc     yes    0.816    0.00448 181.9   <0.001   Inf 0.807  0.824
 afam     yes    0.764    0.01292  59.2   <0.001   Inf 0.739  0.790
 cauc     no     0.725    0.01896  38.2   <0.001   Inf 0.688  0.762
 afam     no     0.727    0.04298  16.9   <0.001 210.9 0.643  0.812
 other    yes    0.752    0.02252  33.4   <0.001 808.6 0.707  0.796
 other    no     0.771    0.06839  11.3   <0.001  95.6 0.637  0.905
Columns: ethnicity, health, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high  
Type:  response 

For example, I'd like to estimate the following differences in predicted probabilities:
avg_predictions(mod, by = c("ethnicity", "health"), type = "response",
            hypothesis = c("b1-b2=0", "b1-b5=0", "b3-b4=0", "b3-b6=0"))

Which produces this:
    Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 % 97.5 %
 b1-b2=0  0.05134     0.0137  3.754  < 0.001 12.5  0.0245 0.0781
 b1-b5=0  0.06406     0.0230  2.789  0.00528  7.6  0.0190 0.1091
 b3-b4=0 -0.00202     0.0470 -0.043  0.96570  0.1 -0.0941 0.0901
 b3-b6=0 -0.04618     0.0710 -0.651  0.51526  1.0 -0.1853 0.0929
Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
Type:  response 

However, rather than using the parameter positions I'd like to do something like this (which doesn't work):
avg_predictions(mod, by = c("ethnicity", "health"), type = "response",
            hypothesis = c("`cauc yes` - `afam yes` = 0"))

I got the term name from running:
avg_predictions(mod, by = c("ethnicity", "health"), type = "response") |> tidy()

Which produces this:
    # A tibble: 6 × 10
  ethnicity health estimate std.error statistic   p.value s.value conf.low conf.high term     
  <fct>     <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    
1 cauc      yes       0.816   0.00448     182.  0           Inf      0.807     0.824 cauc yes 
2 afam      yes       0.764   0.0129       59.2 0           Inf      0.739     0.790 afam yes 
3 cauc      no        0.725   0.0190       38.2 0           Inf      0.688     0.762 cauc no  
4 afam      no        0.727   0.0430       16.9 3.17e- 64   211.     0.643     0.812 afam no  
5 other     yes       0.752   0.0225       33.4 3.74e-244   809.     0.707     0.796 other yes
6 other     no        0.771   0.0684       11.3 1.64e- 29    95.6    0.637     0.905 other no 

Unsure what I may be doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

This is not currently possible. However, I think you can get what you want---much more easily---using the formula syntax.
Note that I'm using the development version from github:
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")

library(marginaleffects)

data("HealthInsurance", package = "AER")
mod <- glm(insurance ~ ethnicity * health + age + married + family + selfemp + region,
  family = binomial(link = "logit"),
  data = HealthInsurance)

avg_predictions(mod,
  by = c("ethnicity", "health"),
  hypothesis = difference ~ reference | health)
#> 
#>        Hypothesis health Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#>  (afam) - (other)    no   -0.0442     0.0808 -0.547  0.58460 0.8 -0.2025 0.1142
#>  (cauc) - (other)    no   -0.0462     0.0710 -0.651  0.51526 1.0 -0.1853 0.0929
#>  (afam) - (other)    yes   0.0127     0.0260  0.490  0.62440 0.7 -0.0382 0.0636
#>  (cauc) - (other)    yes   0.0641     0.0230  2.789  0.00528 7.6  0.0190 0.1091
#> 
#> Type:  response 
#> Columns: hypothesis, health, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high


Hi @Vincent, thanks for your reply. For some reason, I'm unable to install the development version, I get the following error: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:25:10: fatal error: 'iterator' file not found

The output I get using the formula syntax you provided doesn't look the same. I am using marginaleffects version 0.23.0. Hopefully, this feature will be available someday.

Yes, it will be available in the next CRAN version, upcoming in a few weeks.
